# Unable to connect to firebase realtime database python code

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to create a location tracking application that stores location data obtained from GPS in the Firebase real-time database, and I'm writing a Python code that can retrieve data from Firebase. I have tried using the below code but it's not working. The below link has a screenshot of my Firebase console. I'm new to Firebase and I am unable to understand what I am missing can anyone please help me?

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db

if not firebase_admin._apps:
    # Initialize the Firebase app
    cred = credentials.Certificate("/path/to/cred.json")
    firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

# Reference to the 'location' node in the database
ref = db.reference('/')

# Read latitude and longitude data
latitude = ref.child('latitude').get()
longitude = ref.child('longitude').get()

# Print the latitude and longitude
print("Latitude:", latitude)
print("Longitude:", longitude)
```

The output is
`---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 12>()
10
11 # Reference to the 'location' node in the database
---> 12 ref = db.reference('/')
13
14 # Read latitude and longitude data

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/firebase_admin/db.py in reference(path, app, url)
67     """
68     service = _utils.get_app_service(app, _DB_ATTRIBUTE, _DatabaseService)
---> 69     client = service.get_client(url)
70     return Reference(client=client, path=path)
71

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/firebase_admin/db.py in get_client(self, db_url)
796
797         if not db_url or not isinstance(db_url, str):
--> 798             raise ValueError(
799                 'Invalid database URL: "{0}". Database URL must be a non-empty '
800                 'URL string.'.format(db_url))

ValueError: Invalid database URL: "None". Database URL must be a non-empty URL string.[This is structure of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osWBR.png)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the Firebase SDK what the URL is for the database that you want it to access. From the Firebase documentation on [getting started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#python):

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db

# Fetch the service account key JSON file contents
cred = credentials.Certificate('path/to/serviceAccountKey.json')

# Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL': 'https://databaseName.firebaseio.com' # 
})

# As an admin, the app has access to read and write all data, regradless of Security Rules
ref = db.reference('restricted_access/secret_document')
print(ref.get())
```

You're missing the part that I marked with . You can find the URL for your database in the Firebase console.

Comment: Can you please help me with the db.reference, my rules are
 {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
Database structure is https://i.stack.imgur.com/osWBR.png